# Dynamically change fragment destination in bottom navigation

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack

I'm using bottom navigation with navigation component architecture.
I want to change the first fragment destination dynamically. so I have Fragment1 and Fragment2. I want in some conditions, clicking on the first item in bottom nav open the Fragment1 and in other conditions open Fragment2

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like:

```
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        if (it.itemId == ..){
            //navigate to Fragment1 or Fragment2
            true
        }
        //Trigger the original listener for the other items
        NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
        true
    }
```

Comment: Well, Bottom Nav is inside an Activity, how the navigate method does not work on activity, I think.

Comment: Well, Bottom Nav is inside an Activity, how the navigate method does not work on activity, I think.

Comment: @SinaMN75 why? Just use the [`navController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/package-summary#findnavcontroller) and `findNavController().navigate(...)`

Comment: I know, but there's no navigation id from MainActivity (which the bottom nav is placed on) to the destionation I want.

Comment: @SinaMN75 It is not clear how to handle the navigation, but your MainActivity should host a Fragment (a top level destination).

Answer (score 1):

### setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener deprecated

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener{ item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.firstItem -> {
                if(condition){
                    navController.navigate(fragment1)
                }else{
                    navController.navigate(fragment2)
                 }
            }
    }
}
```